# Flutter-background process

Tags: flutter

I have a question about background process in flutter. The app I am building needs to constantly work in the background and use live accelerometer data. I have been over many libraries and tutorials, but I just can find something which will work constantly in the background. I used the [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service)package  and there is a notification on the top of the screen which says "background service- preparing." Any suggestions?

```
void onStart() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  service.setForegroundMode(false);
  
  }




void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
        state == AppLifecycleState.detached) return;

    final isBackground = state == AppLifecycleState.paused;

    if (isBackground) {
      number=1;
    }

    else{
      number=0;
```

Comment: Could you please add your code of the service?

Comment: And then latter in the code I do a process if number=0